# Почему локальные переменные не могут иметь значение по умолчанию?

Tags: java

Почему локальные переменные не могут иметь значение по умолчанию в Java?
Например:

```
static int number1;
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    int number2;
    System.out.println(number1);
    System.out.println(number2);
}
```

Здесь `number1` благополучно выведется, а при выводе `number2` выдаст ошибку:

> The local variable number2 may not have been initialized

Почему так происходит?

Comment: А откуда у вас информация о том, что они не могут иметь значение по умолчанию? Приведите пример.

Comment: @Miron если проинициализировать переменную без значения в методе класса, то на этапе компиляции будет ошибка

Comment: Можно код. На словах не совсем понятно, что имеете ввиду.

Comment: @Miron полагаю речь примерно о таком: https://ideone.com/5XEIkM   Но это лишь догадки

Comment: @СергейМишин да. Это я и имел ввиду

Answer (score -1, accepted):

потому что память для локальных переменных выделяется на стеке
а как выделить память на стеке ?? просто переместить указатель на верхушку стека , не записывая в эту область никакого значения
вообще это не только в java, это справедливо для многих языков, например в с/с++ локальная переменная также не будет инициализирована, то есть в ней буден находится мусор, просто компилятор не выдаст ошибку, а в яве и c# компилятор за этим следит,
а сделано это для производительности, так как легче просто переместить указатель, чем переместить указатель и еще писать туда какието там значения по умолчанию

ну а глобальные переменные хранятся не в стеке, для них есть там гдето специально отведённое место, то есть память под них выделяется один раз в начале работы программы и туда записывается значение по умолчанию, это никак не повлияет на производительность, так как выполняется только вначале

а память для локальных переменных память выделяется на стеке при каждом вызове функции

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106076/discussion-on-answer-by-slavik-------).

Answer (score 3):

Java изначально проектировали так, чтобы в ней невозможны были типичные ошибки, вызывавшие проблемы в корпоративном ПО в предыдущие годы. В частности операции с не инициализированными переменными.

Comment: Но ведь тогда для читателя (автора вопроса) остается актуальным другой вопрос: "Почему так сделали только с локальными переменными, но не полями класса?"

Comment: Потому что семантика поля отличается от семантики переменной. Это очень разные сущности с абсолютно разным поведением и в Java, и в C++, и в любом другом языке с поддержкой ООП.

Comment: Это все понятно, непонятно почему выбрали различные модели поведения по умолчанию для этих различных сущностей (полями и переменными), ведь с полями точно также можно случайно "накосячить", как и с переменными.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive почему в ITIL именно 26 процессов, а не 25 или 27? Потому что подавляющее большинство компаний много лет подряд в своих лучших практиках приходили именно к 26 процессам. Так же и с Java, большинство ошибок в большинстве проектов большинства компаний вызывали именно не инициализированные переменные и отсутствие значений по умолчанию у полей.